# Database design for opt-in emails

Tags: sql-server, database

I have a table of users in SQL Server with all the contact details, personal details etc. When each user signs up to my website they will be given the option to opt-in to 5 different types of emails like:

- I wish to receive emails about new things
- I wish to receive the monthly newsletter

etc etc. I am trying to decide the best way to store this information in a database. My current thinking is to have a seperate table with 5 columns (one for each opt-in) and the value being a bool/bit value.

Since the information wont be required regularly, it will only be required when we want to send mail to user. Are there any better ways / best practices for doing something like this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem with your proposed design is that it becomes difficult to add new email types in the future; you only have 5 now, but what happens when you add a sixth or seventh?.

Instead, I would propose something like:

```
User Table:
UserID (Primary Key)
User Attributes

EmailTemplate Table
EmailTemplateID (Primary key)
Email Template Attributes

UserEmailTemplates
UserID
EmailTemplateID
```

You can easily add new templates, and associate them with users.

Comment: Adding a relation to a database makes the database more complex.  For example, client code will now have to iterate over rows to read mailing lists.  It has to build the web page list of checkboxes dynamically.  This makes sense if you intend to make mailing lists configurable, but tread carefully :)

Comment: I suppose I don't know what's coming further down the track so I should prepare for the future. Thanks guys